# Codes works jsfiddle not working on dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver, jsfiddle

This seems to be a more common problem, but when I try to use code off of jsfiddle (html/css/javascript) it doesn't work. I'm trying to get a CSS animation to repeat onclick, and found some on links on other questions to jsfiddle that work. However, they do not work when I try to do them on DreamWeaver, and I get no error.

I have http://jsfiddle.net/vxcYJ/45/ , http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/9LYAT/, and http://jsfiddle.net/6tZd3/, and none work. On dreamweaver, I believe the third jsfiddle would translate into something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
<style>
.animate {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.initial {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.final {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}​
</style>
<script>
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function()
{
    this.setAttribute('class', 'animate final');
});

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
    this.setAttribute('class', 'initial');
});​
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" id="button" class="animate initial">Click me!</button>​
</body>
</html>
```

one more thing, at the end of the button, this->`â€‹` appears for some reason. If anyone could help me out, that would be greaty appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is failing for two reasons. Firstly, there are two illegal characters at different places in your code. The one you can see which appears next to the button when you run the page, and the second, which is causing an error in the JavaScript, after the webkitTransitionEnd event listener. Secondly, when you try to add the event listeners to your button in the head of your document, it fails because the DOM has not registered with the browser yet.

The following code should work. You might also consider looking at the [jQuery document ready function](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready).

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
<style>
.animate {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.initial {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.final {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}​
</style>

</head>

<body>
<button type="button" id="button" class="animate initial">Click me!</button>​

<script>
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function()
{
    this.setAttribute('class', 'animate final');
});

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
    this.setAttribute('class', 'initial');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works great, thanks.. but, I keep getting `â€‹` next to the button. What is that?

Comment: There's a character somewhere between the closing button tag and the opening script tag. It sounds like it's not visible in the editor you're using (it wasn't in mine). Just try deleting everything between those two tags.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to view the site in the dreamweaver browser? You are using `-webkit` properties. These will only work in webkit browsers such as chrome or safari. Similarly, `-moz` tags will only work in firefox.

I assume dreamweaver doesn't read the `-webkit` tags. Try using `-o` tags for opera, `-webkit` for safari and chrome, `-moz` for firefox and `-ms` for IE. Chrome and safari will read -webkit css but ignore `-moz` and `-o` since they don't know how to read it.

W3 schools has some good examples of supporting all browsers except IE:  http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition4  http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

The `transform` css property (`-webkit-transform` in your code) will work in IE if you add `-ms-transform`: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: The jsfiddles work for me in chrome. Are you testing this locally? If so, are you sure all links are correct? Try view-source: and check all links as the browser sees it.

Comment: the jsfiddle works, but when I copy it into dreamweaver, it stops... Yeah, they're good.

Comment: How do you view it after you've copied it to dreamweaver? I don't think the design tab in dreamweaver (the "dreamweaver browser") will read browser specific tags.

Comment: No, I go to preview in browser and then Chrome