# Issues with implementing fiddle

Tags: jquery, css, jsfiddle

I am working with a fiddle that I found here on the site, and I have modified it to work with what I am trying to accomplish.  I have it working in the fiddle, here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7pdwP/

**HTML**

```
<div id="fish">test 123</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#fish{background-image:url(http://testsite.perseocigar.com/menu_nohover.png);width:120px;height:108px;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#fish').hover(
  function(){$('#fish').css("background-image", "url(http://testsite.perseocigar.com/menu_hover.png)")},
  function(){$('#fish').css("background-image", "url(http://testsite.perseocigar.com/menu_nohover.png)")}
);
```

but making it work on the website, I have apparently missed something that I am guessing is painfully obvious.  I have simply done exactly what I have tried to do on my main site, on a test page, and it's still not working.

http://testsite.perseocigar.com/Untitled-2.html is the link to the test site.

I have tried getting it to work on my local machine, while I build the site, and also tried to see if it's working up on the webserver, and gotten nowhere on both.  Any assistance would be wonderful.

Comment: Checking it in my browser, it looks like you have an invalid character (\u8203) after `... png)")});​`, at the end of your `hover()` function. If you copy and paste-ed, you might have gotten funky invisible character in there.

Comment: I retyped the code entirely, and my result is still the same.

Comment: Alright I recopied things, and apparently the invisible character isn't there anymore, or it finally got ungrouchy.    

To wquist and wirey, much appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this issue and experienced it myself a few times, the best suggestion I read is getting and using Notepad++ to locate the \u8203 character. I use emacs and it points out the character for me when I try saving in iso-8859-1 encoding.

[The EXACT same code doesn't work as it should in Dreamweaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234578/the-exact-same-code-doesnt-work-as-it-should-in-dreamweaver)

[Works in jsFiddle but not in my Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322628/works-in-jsfiddle-but-not-in-my-site)

[Codes works jsfiddle not working on dreamweaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368047/codes-works-jsfiddle-not-working-on-dreamweaver)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your test page in Chrome with the Developer Tools showing and under the Console it gets an error:

```
Unexpected Token ILLEGAL
```

There may be some strange characters at the end of the line. I suggest you delete the line and type it in again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it inside a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#fish').hover(function() {
      $('#fish').css("background-image", "url(http://testsite.perseocigar.com/menu_hover.png)");
   }, function() {
      $('#fish').css("background-image", "url(http://testsite.perseocigar.com/menu_nohover.png)");
   });
});
```

If you want to use the same code for multiple elements.  Don't do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fish').hover(function() {
       $('#fish').css("background-image", "url(images/menu_hover.png)");
    }, function() {
       $('#fish').css("background-image", "url(images/menu_nohover.png)");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#fish1').hover(function() {
       $('#fish1').css("background-image", "url(images/menu_hover.png)");
     }, function() {
       $('#fish1').css("background-image", "url(images/menu_nohover.png)");
      });
 });
```

You can put them all together like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fish,#fish2,#fish3,#fish4,#fish5').hover(function() {
       $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/menu_hover.png)");//<-- Then use 'this' to refer to the current element firing the event
    }, function() {
       $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/menu_nohover.png)");
    });
});
```

Or even better give your elements a class that they share ex.

```
<div id="fish" class="fishhover">test 123</div>
<div id="fish1" class="fishhover">test 123</div>
<div id="fish2" class="fishhover">test 123</div>
<div id="fish3" class="fishhover">test 123</div>
<div id="fish4" class="fishhover">test 123</div>
```

then select them by the class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fishhover').hover(function() {
       $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/menu_hover.png)");//<-- Then use 'this' to refer to the current element firing the event
    }, function() {
       $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/menu_nohover.png)");
    });
});
```

Comment: Call me a novice in this regard, what would I copy into this, and what syntax would I use for it?

Comment: The code you already have.  Just put it inside.  But it does look like you have a character issue that the others have mentioned which would help fix that issue.  Then you also need it inside a document.ready function so that it waits until the dom is ready before trying to attach your hover event handler

Comment: I did what you said with the following  

`<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){  
  
$('#fish').hover(  
  
function () {  
 $('#fish').css("background-image",   "url(http://testsite.perseocigar.com/menu_hover.png)")  
function () {  
 $('#fish').css("background-image",   "url(http://testsite.perseocigar.com/menu_nohover.png)")  
}  
});  
});  
</script>`

Comment: I copied and pasted your code you have your bracket in the wrong place and you're missing a comma.  I updated the answer with what you need.

Comment: Ok spoke too soon on the fix... http://testsite.perseocigar.com/ is what I tried working it into, and I'm back to square one, with nothing.

Comment: You still have an illegal char after the last });  I just copied and pasted it in Notepad ++.  You can either copy and paste my updated code or delete the }); and any spaces after it and retype it in

Comment: I'm still getting nothing on the testsite.  I don't suppose there is a simpler and easier to implement manner of doing a background mouseover through jQuery or CSS?

Comment: What browser are you using?  Also try putting semicolons after the .css() methods

Comment: I am using Chrome on a Mac.  The "Untitled-2" page works fine, but the "index.html" with the same code, just worked into the layout, doesn't work.

Comment: You're missing a closing </div> tag in your html

Comment: Alright closing the DIV did make the one work, but if I add multiple instances, it won't allow for them all to work as well.  How would I make it allow for multiple instances of the same function to work?

Comment: If you are giving them all `id`'s then it's easy.  Just add the id's in your already working code..  `$('#fish,#fish2,#fish3')`.  Or you can make it easier and give them all the same class then just use the class selector $('.theclass').. id's have to be unique.  Also you are missing a closing `div` tag for the `<div class="center">`

Comment: K... So I got the individual ones built, then I moved the CSS to it's own CSS document, and the JS to another file, and called each file individually.  All of a sudden the images didn't preload, and the JS wouldn't load either.  I had to put the JS and CSS back into the index.html file itself in order to get it to work.  Thoughts?

Comment: just give them all a class `fish` the use $('.fish').hover(function() {
      $(this).css("background-image", "url(http://testsite.perseocigar.com/menu_hover.png)");
   }, function() {
      $(this).css("background-image", "url(http://testsite.perseocigar.com/menu_nohover.png)");
   });